# What are the potential problems due to .hgtags not merged into default?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I created a tag in a branch. Then I merged the branch to my default but, at the revision where the tag was added (not where the changeset for the tag itself was added). This means, I did not merge in the .hgtags file into default. Then I closed the branch in which I added the tag(with .hgtags file left as uncommitted). Recently, I realized from reading that this could be problematic, but, I am not clear on what problems might occur in future because of this. Can someone help me understand this? And hopefully a solution to this too.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are a merge of the `.hgtags` files at each head, so there should be no problem.

Here's an example:

```
@  Rev5 - tip - Added tag bar for changeset b67ebc858f17
|
o  Rev4 -  - 3
|
| o  Rev3 -  - Closed.
| |
| o  Rev2 -  - Added tag foo for changeset b67ebc858f17
| |
o |  Rev1 - bar foo - 2
|/
o  Rev0 -  - 1
```

Rev1 was tagged `foo` by Rev2 on a different branch that was then closed.  Both the `foo` and `bar` tags are still present.  Neither version of `.hgtags` that exists on the two branches has both tags.